# FNH Many-to-Many relationship with attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluent-nhibernate

I have three tables as follow:

Content:

```
public class Content
{
    public Content()
    {
        ContentFieldItems = new List<ContentFieldItem>();
        ContentFields = new Dictionary<ContentField, ContentFieldItem>();
        People = new List<Person>();
    }

    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int categoryid { get; set; }
    public virtual int userid { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? date { get; set; }
    public virtual int status { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<ContentField, ContentFieldItem> ContentFields { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ContentFieldItem> ContentFieldItems { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> People { get; set; }
    public virtual string title { get; set; }
}

public class ContentMap : ClassMap<Content>
{
        Id(x => x.id);
        Map(x => x.categoryid);
        Map(x => x.userid);
        Map(x => x.date);
        Map(x => x.status);
        Map(x => x.title);

        HasMany<ContentFieldItem>(x=>x.ContentFields)
            .Table("ContentFieldItem")
            .KeyColumn("contentid")
            .AsMap(f => f.ContentField)
            .Component(c =>
            {
                c.ParentReference(m => m.Content);
                c.References(m => m.ContentField);
                c.Map(m => m.fieldadditionalinfo);
                c.Map(m => m.fieldvalue);
            })
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

            ...
}
```

ContentField:

```
public class ContentField
{
    public ContentField()
    {
        Contents = new List<Content>();
    }

    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual string field { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddContentField(Content content, 
        ContentFieldItem contentfielditem)
    {
        Contents.Add(content);
        content.ContentFields.Add(this, contentfielditem);
    }
}

public class ContentFieldMap : ClassMap<ContentField>
{
    public ContentFieldMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id);
        Map(x => x.field);
        Map(x => x.categoryid);
        Map(x => x.status);
        Map(x => x.type);
        Map(x => x.showonall);
    }
}
```

ContentFieldItem:

```
public class ContentFieldItem
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual string fieldvalue { get; set; }
    public virtual string fieldadditionalinfo { get; set; }
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentField ContentField { get; set; }
}

public class ContentFieldItemMap : ClassMap<ContentFieldItem>
{
    public ContentFieldItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id);
        Map(x => x.fieldvalue);
        Map(x => x.fieldadditionalinfo);
        References(x => x.Content, "contentid");
        References(x => x.ContentField, "fieldid");
    }
}
```

These three tables at the same time I want to create a way of inter-related. 
I want to create a ContentFieldItem with relation Content through contentid and ContentField through fieldid and some more parameters.I think this can be done with many-to-many without parameters but i have to do with parameters, how is this possible with fluent nhibernate?

and now m getting "Could not determine type for: Project.Models.ContentField".

Comment: `HasMany<ContentFieldItem>(x=>x.ContentFields)` should be `HasMany(x=>x.ContentFields)` or `HasMany<ContentFieldItem, ContentFieldItem>(x=>x.ContentFields)`

Comment: what is `IList<ContentFieldItem> ContentFieldItems` good for? `ContentFields.Values` give you the same result

Comment: gave the same error in two ways..

Comment: what does the stacktrace give you as source of this error? Which mapping does cause it?

Comment: gives [MappingException: Could not determine type for: Chotoox.Models.ContentField, Chotoox, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(ContentField)] and its because of mapping in ContentMap

Comment: if you comment out `c.References(m => m.ContentField);` does it go away? is the assembly with ContentFieldMap in the same folder as the assembly where you call `x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ContentFieldMap>();`?

Comment: when i comment out the line gives the same error. can not we make another way? i tried bi-drectional mapping but getting "object references an unsaved transient instance" when i trying to add new row. i can solve this thing with using two-step .SaveOrUpdate but this not the right way i guess.

Comment: if commenting out does give the same erro, it isn't the reference. But comments are not the right thing to debug it. maybe we can move somewhere else? Any ideas where?

Answer (score 0):

i would do

```
public class Content
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<ContentField, ContentFieldInfo> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class ContentField
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ContentFieldInfo
{
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentField Field { get; set; }

    public virtual string Values { get; set; }
    public virtual string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}

class ContentMap : ClassMap<Content>
{
    public ContentMap()
    {
        Id(...);

        Map(c => c.Title);

        HasMany(c => c.Fields)
            .Table("ContentFieldItem")
            .KeyColumn("contentid")
            .AsMap(fieldinfo => fieldinfo.Field)
            .Component(comp => 
            {
                comp.ParentReference(fi => fi.Content);
                comp.References(fi => fi.ContentField);
                comp.Map(fi => fi.Value);
                ...
            });
    }
}

class ContentFieldMap : ClassMap<ContentField>
{
    public ContentFieldMap()
    {
        Id(...);

        Map(c => c.Name);
    }
}
```

can you clarify what you mean with `ContentField through fieldid and some more parameters.`?

Hope this helps

Comment: its just a wrong sentence. im getting "Could not determine type for: Project.Models.ContentField" error and couldnt solve yet.

Comment: @bakbeyimsanaikiciftlafimvar: have you added the ContentFieldMap to your sessionfactory?

Comment: yes. I added the following: x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ContentFieldMap>();